# Rollup failed to resolve import while creating build on Ubantu for vite based react app, locally its working fine

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
Rollup failed to resolve import "notistack" from "/var/www/html/src/layouts/MainLayout.jsx".
[stderr]This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
```

When I am creating build on ubantu server facing above error, I think its because of vite rollup config

```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import * as path from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000
  },
  plugins: [react()]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have `@notistack` on your `dependencies` entry in your `package.json` file.

```
// using yarn
yarn add -D notistack
// using npm
npm install -g notistack
```

The command could fix it.

Comment: Its there, @sampixel

Comment: i would say to check what's inside `devDependencies` that make the build work fine. I've recently faced a similar issue with a package and resolved by installing the missing package in the right object in package.json, @SanketPatil